# Local folder dissapears in Windows 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I am using `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` for storing the SQLite database and other files. It works fine but sometimes the folder disappear.

I can check it using Windows Explorer and going to
`C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Packages`

I suspect that it disappear when I am debugging my app and maybe I close it, or some other similar thing, but I am not sure.

Somebody do know under which circumstances Windows 8 can delete a local folder?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are not clearing application state when you debug! This is a setting in the project's properties page. It looks like this. `uninstall and then re-install my package` should NOT be checked in your circumstance!

[image]

Comment: No, it is not the case. The checkbox is off

Comment: I'm new to Win8 dev and having this same problem  running unit tests and have verified that the uninstall/reinstall pacakge option is unchecked (which it seems to be by default). The test is testing logic that creates a file. I see the folder & file created while the test is running (or debugging) and then disappear when the test is complete. I'm at a loss...

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me when I delete the obj/bin folders. Visual studio will create a new folder there and discard the old one.

What this seems to be is that visual studio has found that it needs to uninstall/install the app you're developing. Uninstalling an app means deleting the old folder and its contents.

Answer (score 0):

So I am using the same location to store files, important to my app and a few times had the same issue- all the files disappeared sometimes- but after reading this post a realized something- yes @McAden is right- visual studio reinstalled your application- for me this happened every time i changed something into the app manifest- so this is it - every time you change something into the app manifest Visual studio reinstalls the application and you lose all of your data at ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder- this was the deal with me- i hope it will be helpful for somebody.